# Tensor in signal processing

Tags: image-processing

I saw a lot of use of tensor in signal processing. What is the intuition behind it? Is it simply a common representation for audio (1D), image (2D) and video (3D) signals?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has little to do with intuition. Tensors are rigorously defined *mathematical* objects, and in general simple arrays don't qualify as tensors. Specifically, signals are not tensors.

In the language of mathematics, and there the field of differential geometry, a tensor is a linear function with several arguments. It is therefore also called a *multi-linear form*. It is used to describe properties of manifolds at a single point.

A point on a (smooth) manifold comes with a tangent space that contains all possible "direction" at that point, where a direction is really just a tangent vector at that point. This tangent space at a single point is a vector space and it has the same dimension as the manifold.

The tangent space has a natural so called dual space, which contains the linear functions that map tangent space vectors to real numbers. This is the *cotangent space*, and it's also a vector space of the dimension of the manifold.

A tensor is now (roughly) a linear function that maps any number of dimensions between the tangent space, the cotangent space and the real numbers.

Tensors typically don't come as singles but in so called *bundles*, which are the disjoint union of the tensors of all points of the manifold. For example if you have a vector at every point of the manifold then the whole structure is called a vector bundle. Similarly, tensor bundles associate a tensor with every point on the manifold, usually in a smooth way.

In signal processing you can encounter tensors, but usually they are called differently. For example in video processing the image is your manifold (or rather, a function on a 2-dimensional manifold giving the brightness or color for each point) and the velocity field that describes the local motion is a rank 1 tensor field (or bundle) on that manifold.

Tensors also show up a lot in volume data processing, where tensors can describe local properties of the volume data. For example if you have a doppler ultrasonic tomography image, then the velocity data in each voxel is a tensor field as would be mechanical stress in tomographic material analysis.

For a 1-dimensional signals tensors often come in the form of derivative operators. For example if you have a signal $s(t)$, then the operator $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ is a tensor field of rank 1, or just a vector field. More generally, if you multiply that operator with a smooth function $g(t)$, then all possible vector fields on the manifold the signal lives on are of the form $g(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$

To sum up, tensors are a description of differential properties of manifolds. If you want to understand them, you'll have to study differential geometry.

Comment: good answer, can you elaborate on the mapping of the tangent space vectors to real numbers? what does this real valued signal represent?

Comment: @geometrikal: You can imagine this map as a generalization of the directional derivative of a function on the manifold and the construction of the gradient of that function. The directional derivative of a scalar function F at a point p will result in a real (or maybe complex) number that depends on the direction represented by a vector field at that same point p. Instead of evaluating the derivative of the function every time you change that direction v, you can also introduce the gradient of F at p and simply evaluate the scalar product <grad F,v>.

Comment: Modern differential geometry calls the linear function <grad F, * > a covector that live in the cotangent space at p. This abstraction allows you to remove the need of having a scalar product defined, because whatever linear product is used is already contained in the cotangent vector. These covectors are also called "differentials" and usually written dF.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is not related to the tensor fields. There is a growing area in signal processing, namely tensor factorizations. Here tensor is simply a multiway array - generalization of the matrix. So, yes, a video is a tensor with dimensions $m\times n \times T$ here $T$ is a frame count.

Tensor related methods are not restricted to the video processing because in many data analysis problems, data comes in tensor form, for instance think of a tensor encodes the relations between $user \times user \times product$.

You can see an audio processing application of the tensor factorization from [here](http://www.cmpe.boun.edu.tr/~cemgil/papers/simsekli-yilmaz-cemgil-icassp2012.pdf).

Comment: You're right that tensor product and tensor factorizations are important in signal processing. But contrary to common belief the objects they work on or result in are *not* automatically tensors. In fact, the typical tensor product works on ordinary vector spaces. So your conclusion that a video is a tensor is not really correct. At least from a mathematical stand point.

Comment: Yes, true, in this context tensor is just a name, from a rigorous point of view a video is not a tensor of course. But in this area, terminology goes like this in practice.